# Question about the factors of a number (apart from 2 consecutive numbers)

Tags: factoring

> Pr. 13. In a class, 25 students were lined up. The teacher wrote a number on the board.
> • The first student said the number was divisible by 1.
> • Student number 2 said it was divisible by 2.
> • Student 3 said it was divisible by 3.
> ...
> • This went on until the 25th student.
> The teacher said everyone was correct except two boys, named Jack and Jill, who were wrong. They were standing one immediately after the other in the line.
> What are their positions in the line?

I had no idea how to start, so I listed the factors and multiples under 25 of the numbers under 25:

```
1: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
2: 1,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24
3: 1,6,9,12,15,18,21,24
4: 1,2,8,12,16,20,24
5: 1,10,15,20,25
6: 1,2,3,12,18,24
7: 1,14,21
8: 1,2,4,16,24,
9: 1,3,18
10: 1,2,5,20
11: 1,22
12: 1,2,3,4,6,24
13: 1
14: 1,2,7
15: 1,3,5
16: 1,2,4,8
17: 1
18: 1,2,9
19: 1
20: 1,2,4,5
21: 1,3,7
22: 1,2,11
23: 1
24: 1,2,3,4,6,8,12
25: 1,5
```

I thought I could choose 17 and 19, but they aren't consecutive!
How shall I attempt and solve this question?

Comment: Boys are not usually named Jill...

Comment: Hint: Look for two consecutive prime powers, greater than $25/2$.

Comment: @TonyK, I kind of agree :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the responses had been correct, then the number would have to be a multiple of

$$2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5^2 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23.$$

The obvious try, which works, is that neither $(16)$ nor $(17)$ divides the number.

Comment: oh. the question now seems _so_ ovbious!